# The entity set or function import 'name' is not defined in the entity container 'contextName'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6.0 and Code First to migrate a legacy database schema to a new schema.

I'm getting an unexpected error upon querying `EMPLOYEES`:

> The entity set or function import 'EMPLOYEES' is not defined in the entity container 'WebModel'. Near escaped identifier, line 1, column 14.

Here's the relevant parts of the context class.

```
public partial class WebModel : DbContext
{
    public WebModel : base("name=WebModel") { }

    public virtual DbSet<LEGACY_EMPLOYEE> EMPLOYEES { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

`LEGACY_EMPLOYEE` is a class that was generated by the built-in POCO generator from the legacy schema, and `Employee` is part of the new code first schema I've converting to.

In isolation, either one works. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The `public virtual DbSet<LEGACY_EMPLOYEE> EMPLOYEES { get; set; }` property can't have the same case insensitive name as another `DbSet`.

To clear this up, rename it to something else, like `public virtual DbSet<LEGACY_EMPLOYEE> LEGACY_EMPLOYEES { get; set; }`